# If element contains string then replace it

Tags: jquery, string, text, replace

I want to rename all the english daynames in these:

```
<td class="date" style="text-align: right !important;">2016-01-07 (Thu)</td>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(".date:contains('Mon'), .date:contains('Tue'), .date:contains('Wed'), .date:contains('Thu'), .date:contains('Fri'), .date:contains('Sat'), .date:contains('Sun')").html(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/Mon/g, 'H');
    return text.replace(/Tue/g, 'K');
    return text.replace(/Wed/g, 'Sz');
    return text.replace(/Thu/g, 'Cs');
    return text.replace(/Fri/g, 'P');
    return text.replace(/Sat/g, 'Szo');
    return text.replace(/Sun/g, 'V');
});
```

But it wont replace the given texts.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execution will leave the function after the first `return` statement. Instead, you need to chain the `replace()` calls:

```
$(".date:contains('Mon'), .date:contains('Tue'), .date:contains('Wed'), .date:contains('Thu'), .date:contains('Fri'), .date:contains('Sat'), .date:contains('Sun')").html(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/Mon/g, 'H')
        .replace(/Tue/g, 'K')
        .replace(/Wed/g, 'Sz')
        .replace(/Thu/g, 'Cs')
        .replace(/Fri/g, 'P')
        .replace(/Sat/g, 'Szo')
        .replace(/Sun/g, 'V');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/2adowsdb/)

Comment: I'm so dumb... I forgot that I can return only one thing.
Thanks for the answer though, it works like magic now!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could write 7 smaller functions, for example:

```
$(".date:contains('Mon')).html(function(i, text) { return text.replace(/Mon/g, 'H'); });
$(".date:contains('Tue')).html(function(i, text) { return text.replace(/Tue/g, 'K'); });
    ...
```